# SVM: Representer Theorem or KKT conditions?

Tags: svm

If we need to solve the SVM problem in its primal formulation, is it correct to use a predictor derived from the Representer Theorem written as:

$f(\vec{x}) = \sum_{i=1}^{l} \alpha_i K(\vec{x}_i, \vec{x}) + b$

with $\alpha_i \in \mathbb{R}$,
or a predictor derived from the KKT optimality conditions:

$f(\vec{x}) = \sum_{i=1}^{l} \alpha_i y_i K(\vec{x}_i, \vec{x}) + b$

with $\alpha_i \geq 0$?